# Como disparar um evento quando o valor de uma variável mudar?

Tags: javascript

É possível criar um evento personalizado para que quando uma variável tiver seu valor alterado algo aconteça? Se sim, como fazer isso? Por exemplo:

Em um jogo de truco eu quero que quando a variável estado mude para "bot" eu quero que o bot jogue, várias funções podem alterar o valor dessa variável a qualquer momento.

Comment: Dê um cenário onde precisa de utilizar isso, para que seja mais fácil darmos uma resposta que sirva ao que pretende.

Comment: Isso é um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy). A solução que quer aplicar não é a ideal para o seu problema. Tente ser mais especifico e detalhado, de preferência colocando um bloco de código onde quer utilizar isso.

Comment: queria que existisse algo como quando (estado == "bot") faca x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível utilizar um `setInterval()` para ficar verificando de *tempo em tempo* (ex., a cada 1 segundo) se a variável `estado` mudou de valor:

```js
estado = ""; // valor inicial da variável (neste caso, vazio)
setInterval(function(){
 if(estado == "bot"){ // verifico se a variável mudou de valor
  estado = ""; // volto o valor original da variável
  console.log("vez do bot"); //mostra no console que é a vez do bot (só exemplo, pode apagar esta linha)
                // aqui vc dispara o evento
 }
 estado = "bot"; // só um exemplo de quando a variável mudar
},5000); // coloquei 5 segundos para exemplo. Talvez 1 segundo seja o ideal
```

```html
Aguarde 5 segundos...
```

- Dentro da função coloquei `estado = "bot";` apenas como exemplo, pode deletar essa linha.

Answer (score 2):

Como disse o Victor na resposta dele:

> O seu problema real é que "várias funções podem alterar o valor dessa variável a qualquer momento". É esse o problema real que você tem que resolver.

Uma das maneiras de resolver é usar um objeto com um *getter* e um *setter* em vez da variável. A vantagem é que todas as suas atribuições de valor (e leituras) podem continuar como estão (se já estiver usando um objeto), ou muito parecidas (se estiver usando variáveis mesmo).

Um exemplo:

```js
var estado = {
    set jogador(valor) {
        console.log('Aqui você intercepta a troca do valor');
    
        this._jogador = valor;
    },
    get jogador() {
        return this._jogador;
    },
    
    _jogador: 'humano'
};

console.log('jogador atual', estado.jogador);
estado.jogador = 'bot';
console.log('jogador atual', estado.jogador);
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema real é que "*várias funções podem alterar o valor dessa variável a qualquer momento*". É esse o problema real que você tem que resolver.

Depois de resolvido o problema de a variável ser alterada em vários locais possíveis, você aplica o [padrão de projeto Observer](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer).

A solução seria criar um código mais ou menos assim:

```
var Turno = (function() {
    var estado = {};
    var tipo = "player";
    var listeners = [];

    estado.adicionarListener = function(listener) {
        listeners.push(listener);
    };

    estado.getTipo = function() {
        return tipo;
    };

    estado.vezDePlayer = function() {
        tipo = "player";
        for (var i in listeners) {
            listeners[i]();
        }
    };

    estado.vezDeBot = function() {
        tipo = "bot";
        for (var i in listeners) {
            listeners[i]();
        }
    };

    return estado;
)();
```

E então você deve trocar todos os lugares que tenha isso:

```
estado = "bot";
```

Por isso:

```
Turno.vezDeBot();
```

E também trocar isso:

```
estado = "player";
```

Por isso:

```
Turno.vezDeBot();
```

E por fim trocar isso:

```
if (estado == "bot") {
```

Por isso:

```
if (Turno.getTipo() === "bot") {
```

Quando você quiser que algo aconteça assim que seja a vez do bot:

```
Turno.adicionarListener(function() {
    if (Turno.getTipo() !== "bot") return;

    // Fazer algo acontecer assim que o bot assumir a vez.
});
```